# Aligning textview with other textviews

Tags: android, textview

I have a problem aligning my TextViews correctly:

This is my CardView with 3 TextView with a list of strings: [image: Photo 1]

But my alignment is kinda bad: [image: Photo 2]

I was trying to align with lineSpacingExtra, but it didn't really work. Is there any way to change that?

**My .xml code:**

```
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="10dp"
    app:cardBackgroundColor="@android:color/white"
    app:cardCornerRadius="5dp"
    app:cardElevation="0.5dp">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="center_vertical"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:paddingBottom="10dp"
                android:paddingEnd="15dp"
                android:paddingStart="15dp"
                android:paddingTop="15dp">

                <View
                    android:layout_width="8dp"
                    android:layout_height="8dp"
                    android:background="@drawable/rounded_shape" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/pav_tvarkarastis"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
                    android:fontFamily="@font/open_sans"
                    android:text="TVARKARAŠTIS"
                    android:textColor="#777"
                    android:textSize="12sp"
                    android:textStyle="bold" />

            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal|center"
                android:orientation="horizontal">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/pamoka1_nr"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:lineSpacingExtra="4.9dp"
                    android:layout_marginEnd="10dp"
                    android:layout_marginStart="15dp"
                    android:fontFamily="@font/open_sans_bold"
                    android:text="1"
                    android:textSize="15sp"
                    android:textColor="@color/colorPrimary" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/pamoka1_pav"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:lineSpacingExtra="5dp"
                    android:fontFamily="@font/open_sans"
                    android:text="Matematika"
                    android:textSize="15sp"
                    android:textColor="#777"/>

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/pamoka1_laikas"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:lineSpacingExtra="8.25dp"
                    android:layout_marginEnd="15dp"
                    android:fontFamily="@font/open_sans_light"
                    android:gravity="fill_vertical|end"
                    android:text="08:00 - 08:45"
                    android:textSize="12sp"
                    android:textColor="#777"/>

            </LinearLayout>

    </LinearLayout>

</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

**Code (if it is necessary):**

```
public void setTvarkarastis() {

    TextView tv_pamokos_pav = view.findViewById(R.id.pamoka1_pav);
    TextView tv_pamokos_nr = view.findViewById(R.id.pamoka1_nr);
    TextView tv_pamokos_laikas = view.findViewById(R.id.pamoka1_laikas);
    String pamoku_pav = "";
    String pamoku_nr = "";
    String pamoku_laik = "";
    String[] array_pamokuLaikas = new String[] {
            "08:00 - 08:45",
            "08:55 - 09:40",
            "09:50 - 10:35",
            "10:55 - 11:40",
            "12:00 - 12:45",
            "12:55 - 13:40",
            "13:50 - 14:35",
            "14:45 - 15:30"
    };

    for(int i = 0; i < kelintos.size(); i++) {
        if(kelintos.contains("" + i)) {
            int index = kelintos.indexOf("" + i);
            pamoku_pav += pamokos.get(index) + "\n";
            pamoku_nr += kelintos.get(index) + "\n";
            pamoku_laik += array_pamokuLaikas[i-1] + "\n";
        }
    }

    tv_pamokos_pav.setText(pamoku_pav);
    tv_pamokos_nr.setText(pamoku_nr);
    tv_pamokos_laikas.setText(pamoku_laik);
}
```

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Try to add `"fill_vertical|end|center_vertical"` flag in TextView with Id `android:id="@+id/pamoka1_laikas"`

Comment: Thanks for the reply. It was already like that